# What are the differences on the logon types choices on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, server

I have installed jenkins before on some machines from the .war file and the from the web page installed as a windows service.

Now I am trying to install it on a different machine through the .msi file, but I am having an issue, on the installation steps there is one step which asks me "Logon type" which gives me 2 choices as it can be seen on the image. I do not know the differences between them and also it only lets me choose run service as a local system(not recommended) adn this install jenkins on the windows/system32 folder. I have been loking to tutorials but it seems all of them skip this step. I have also search on here with no success. Does anyone know the difference and how to use the recommended one? I have tried to enter my windows and jenkins credentials and nothing. What user and password are to be entered on this window?

[image: Jenkins Menu]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582616/4309588

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jenkins installation windows 10 "Service Logon Credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410442/jenkins-installation-windows-10-service-logon-credentials)

Comment: If running Windows Home, you may find this useful as a first step: https://www.itechtics.com/enable-secpol-msc-windows-11/ then follow the instructions on the official jenkins page: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/#invalid-service-logon-credentials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest reading the [old installation documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=3604487#content/view/3604487), the [new installer updates](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/02/01/windows-installers/), the actual [Install on Windows](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#windows) doc, as well as MS Doc
[Using the LocalSystem Account as a Service Logon Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/the-localsystem-account), S/O explanation [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510170/598141) and S/O explanation [Why running a service as Local System is bad on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1730486/598141).

In short, you want to create a specific service account to run Jenkins because it's safer than running as highly privileged LocalSystem - Win equivalent of root. That account must have LogonAsService rights.

See MS docs [Enable Service Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scsm/enable-service-log-on-sm?view=sc-sm-2019)  and [Log on as a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/log-on-as-a-service)

Also, the new installer is literally new,  ..  I have raised [JENKINS-63477](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63477) to get documentation improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am gonna read the links and hopefully it will be clear

Comment: fyi: I have raised a jira ticket for this and updated my response. If you find my response helpful, please mark as answered (and upvote) so others can reference this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Windows specialist (I have just installed Jenkins on Linux boxes) but I think that screen refers to the operating system starting the Jenkins' service on your machine.

What a would do is create a local user for Jenkins, with the proper permissions so it can have access to what it needs.

As Local machine it will have a full access to the whole computer and services.

The tricky part is finding the proper permissions, but you can try to check on Jenkins website to see if the have a guide.

Hope this helped

Answer (score -5):

I experience this problem also, It happens that the new jenkins at this time does not support the current Java JDK 15, so what I did was to uninstall java 15 and instead used java 11 JDK
check from your command line with
java --version
Once you have the right JDK
From you cmd line; navigate to where you have Jenkins installed C:\Program Files\Jenkins and then run >java -jar jenkins.war
Follow the command from there, it should be smooth

Comment: If I could give this more negative rating, I would. The original question makes no mention of JDK, though it is well documented Jenkins only supports JDK 8 or 11. Running `java -jar jenkins.war` does not explain what account to run it under, which is the OP's issue. Further, if you run as cmd, then as soon as you close the window, the app stops. You do not discuss how to run as a service, which can still be done but again comes back to under what user - yourself? Suggest deleting your "answer".