# Install Jenkins on windows with service account

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install Jenkins on Windows 10. When I run the windows installer, it asks for a user account. Which account is that? I create an account in Jenkins but when I do test connection, it says "User name and/or password incorrect".
Can someone please help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows 10 what you can do is:

- use the window search bar to search for *Local Security Policy* and open it.
- Click on *Local Policies*
- Click on *User Rights Assignment*
- By the right side showing the policies, open *Logon as a service*
- Click on *Add User or Group* button.
- In the input part written enter the object name, input the account name you created that you want to change to a service account.
- Once you have inputed it, click on *Check Name* to verify.
- finally click *ok* and you are good to go, you can now use the account while installing Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, following is what I am guessing,

- If you are installing Jenkins from an installer and it asks for windows username/password, then your login might need higher privilege(Administrator) rights to install further.
- If the installation is successful, then initial username is "admin" and password could be located at,

  - $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword
  - cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
    Check these links - [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849253/how-to-get-username-and-password-for-recently-installed-jenkins), [windows](https://intellipaat.com/community/26950/default-credentials-for-jenkins-after-installation-windows-10-jenkins-default-password)

Comment: The installer is asking what Windows equivalent OSUser to jenkins the application will be installed under and the service (ie: app) will run under. Not a jenkins login.

Comment: In Run prompt, type "services.msc". Search Jenkins in the list. Right click, properties, log on - You will be able to take it from there based on how its configured and installed.

Comment: But that's the thing ... OP is installing Jenkins "for the first time" using the windows installer... " I run the windows installer, it asks for a user account.". There will be no Jenkins service yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you got the error when you tried to install Jenkins and selected Logon Type **Run as service as local or domain user**. 
If so, I ran into the same problem. I solved it by creating a new user on windows.

1. Type **Add, edit or remove other users** and double klick it
   [image]
2. In the new dialog under **Other users** select **Add someone else to this PC** 
   [image]
3. Click on **I don't have this person's sign-in information**
   [image]
4. Click on **Add a user without a Microsoft account**
   [image]
5. Enter username and password
   [image]
6. Enter the new credentials into Jenkins installer dialog
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [my anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546100/598141) to a similar question. It is asking for a Windows account with "Log on as a service" permission. This is the account Jenkins app will run under.

Answer (score -1):

These steps helped for me:

1. Download the latest Jenkins war from https://www.jenkins.io/download/
2. Keep it program files folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins)
3. Start Jenkins (java -jar jenkins.war)
4. Check console.
5. Now stop this Jenkins instance (Cntrl +C)
6. In "Services", find the Jenkins and set the credentials one more time in the "Logon" tab. Save changes.
7. Now start the old instance through service, it should start normally and old jobs should appear at the console.