# How to run jenkins's job as a specific user?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins cluster in my company runs builds as root user.
How to configure cluster/build to run as a different user? Without root privileges ?

Comment: For jenkins 2.375.3 on Ubuntu 22.04, any Bash script builds run as jenkins, BUT the odd thing is, if you add the jenkins user to a group, the jenkins app does not register it, and the user running the commands is jenkins:jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builds always run under the user that runs the node agent process. So your options are

- **Specify a different user for connecting the node**, or
- **Switch to a different user during the build** (e.g., via `sudo` in a shell build step). This is more flexible, but plugin related-code (like SCM checkout) will still run under the root account.

Comment: sudo also requires either setting the sudoers properly on the hosts, or otherwise possibly exposing the password to the sudo in the logs or the properties. You'd also liekly get permission issues at some point. Kinda surprised OP marked this as answer as accepted, but I guess they are te deciders.

Comment: OP did not ask about the security implications of his setup. While your security concerns are certainly valid in general, there can be good reasons for not changing the connection at this point. Invoking `sudo` (or `su`) as root user for switching to a non-root user has no (further) impact on security.

Comment: sudo will prompt for password when switching user.

Comment: @ChangZhao: this is not necessarily true; it depends on the configuration of `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

[Any agent can be configure](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/distributed+builds)d to be launched as *any* user, so do that.

Advise your company Jenkins Admin to change Jenkins immediately to [NOT run as root](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). It does not need root (can be a daemon/service tho) and [increases your risk exposure](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/security/) .  We use [Java Service Wrapper](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon) (RUN_AS_USER=jenkins) in Unix. The new [windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546100/598141) prompts you for the account to use (don't use System despite being the default).

Comment: How do you get any agent to run as any user? for me, despite setting up an agent to run as a specific user user, it still tries to run on that agent as the Jenkins user