# jenkins installation windows 10 “Service Logon Credentials”

Tags: jenkins, installation

I don't know Jenkins at all. I want to install Jenkins on Windows 10. I downloaded the installer and ran it, but I have a problem. I don't know what to enter in the "Account" and "Password" fields on the "Service Logon Credentials" stage.

Comment: Did you not come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546100/598141) ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this link to install Jenkins in windows 10 if you couldn't use the service log on credentials.
https://youtu.be/no98HueS3Ws

1. Go to https://www.jenkins.io/download/
2. Download the Generic Java Package(.war)
3. Create a new folder called jenkins in C drive and move the jenkins.war to that folder
4. Open command prompt, navigate to the jenkins folder in C drive
5. Run this war file using the command " java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090"
6. Jenkins will be downloaded and installed.
7. You will get an administrator password when you are doing it for the first time.
8. Copy the password
9. Open the jenkins in localhost:9090 and give the administrator password
10. you are now good to go

Comment: This is a workaround and not the same outcome as it's not running as a  service. It's also seems to layout the exact steps as the [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/war-file/), so just refer to that. Suggest deleting the answer and the question.