# Where to find domain credentials for Jenkins 2.289.3 Windows Installer?

Tags: windows, jenkins

On my new Windows 10, as I am trying to install Jenkins, I encountered following prompt:

[image]

Since I don't know what local or domain user creds to enter, I keep on getting following error:

> Error logging on DESKTOP-xxxx\user: The user name or password is incorrect

From reading the official doc, I am understanding that this is something new that Jenkins installer is doing for running as a Windows service, but where do I find these credentials on Windows?

Comment: See my [response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537185/what-are-the-differences-on-the-logon-types-choices-on-jenkins/63546100#63546100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences on the logon types choices on jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537185/what-are-the-differences-on-the-logon-types-choices-on-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the applications when installed on Windows OS may want to run as a service using either the local system account or a specific account which needs specific permissions on the OS. Please use any local admin account which already there on the system where you are trying to install Jenkins. If the system is joined to a domain, prefer to use an domain account which has admin privileges on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The worst advice to grand admin permissions for a single service.

You need to use local existing credentials from your windows system (if it's not connected to a domain) or a domain creds. Don't use admin creds for the installation.