# Jenkins installation windows 10 "Service Logon Passwords" |I have added Administrator User in Local Policy-logon Services but dont know password

Tags: jenkins, passwords, devops, credentials

[image]I am new to jenkins.

1.I downloaded Jenkins from https://www.jenkins.io/download/
2.Added Administrator User to Log on services
3.Now what password should I enter to login in to Jenkins.

Comment: That dialog is not to login into Jenkins , rather the Windows account Jenkins (service) will run under. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546100/598141) for more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences on the logon types choices on jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537185/what-are-the-differences-on-the-logon-types-choices-on-jenkins)